# Is Django application affected by the server timezone?

Tags: django, django-timezone

I have the below settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = UTC
USE_TZ = True
```

My server timezone is `UTC+1` and the end user's timezone is `UTC+2`. Should I care about the server timezone or it is not related at all?

Answer (score 0):

Server time zone isn't related in most cases. Your application will use UTC. The most common application in python uses `datetime.datetime.now(tzInfo=None)` which will automatically pass `tzInfo` as None when you call `datetime.datetime.now()` . Unless you specify what timezone `tzInfo` is, the datetime object will always return UTC.